# How to Create project asp.net core web2 app with .net 4.8?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2022

I install visual studio 2022 and I want to Create project asp.net core web2 app  with .net 4.8 .

When I try to create asp.net core app in vs get me *.net6 (long term support)* and .net core3(out of suport) !!!

How to fix it?

Comment: .Net Core is not .Net Framework. So,  ASP.Net Core will not work with .Net Framework 4.8. You have to decide which technology you want to use.

Comment: You right......

Comment: @MarkusMeyer you really should post that as the answer.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.NET Core` and `.NET Framework` are different implementations of `.NET`:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

[ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/overview) uses the `.NET Framework`
[ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) uses `.NET Core`

You have to decide which implementation you want to use.
IMO there's no supported way to combine both implementations.

[Choose between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: This is NOT correct, ASP.NET Core is supported to by .NET Framework.